# Need to access array values from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrayobject

I got array value from API.

```
model\Quote Object
(
    [quote_reference:protected] => 12345
    [proposals:protected] => model\Proposals Object
        (
            [proposal:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => model\Proposal Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => prp_3453453453sdfsd
                            [fees_included:protected] => 1
                            [charged_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                    [amount:protected] => 105.00
                                )
                            [credited_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => MAD
                                    [amount:protected] => 1000.00
                                )
                            [principal_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                    [amount:protected] => 100.00
                                )
                            [expiration_date:protected] => DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 2016-04-07 02:12:55.682000
                                    [timezone_type] => 1
                                    [timezone] => -05:00
                                )
                            [destination_service_tag:protected] => 
                            [corridor_tag:protected] => 
                            [resource_type:protected] => proposal
                            [additional_data_list:protected] => model\AdditionalDataList Object
                                (
                                    [data:protected] => model\Data Object
                                        (
                                            [data_field:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => model\DataField Object
                                                        (
                                                            [name:protected] => 811
                                                            [value:protected] => 123
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => model\DataField Object
                                                        (
                                                            [name:protected] => 851
                                                            [value:protected] => 456
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [item_count:protected] => 2
                                    [resource_type:protected] => list
                                )
                            [wholesale_fx_rate:protected] => 
                        )
                    [1] => model\Proposal Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => prp_456sgdfgsdfg                                [fees_included:protected] => 1
                            [charged_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                    [amount:protected] => 100.00
                                )
                            [credited_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => MAD
                                    [amount:protected] => 950.00
                                )
                            [principal_amount:protected] => model\Amount Object
                                (
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                    [amount:protected] => 100.00
                                )
                            [expiration_date:protected] => DateTime Object
                                (
                                    [date] => 2016-04-07 02:22:55.682000
                                    [timezone_type] => 1
                                    [timezone] => -05:00
                                )
                            [destination_service_tag:protected] => 
                            [corridor_tag:protected] => 
                            [resource_type:protected] => proposal
                            [additional_data_list:protected] => model\AdditionalDataList Object
                                (
                                    [data:protected] => model\Data Object
                                        (
                                            [data_field:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => model\DataField Object
                                                        (
                                                            [name:protected] => 811
                                                            [value:protected] => 123
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => model\DataField Object
                                                        (
                                                            [name:protected] => 851
                                                            [value:protected] => 456
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [item_count:protected] => 2
                                    [resource_type:protected] => list
                                )
                            [wholesale_fx_rate:protected] => 
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I need to access both `proposal` array values at `0` and `1` index position.

I Tried:

```
$arrayobject->proposals->proposal[0];
```

Getting error:

> Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property model\Quote::$proposal

Any idea or help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So look to see if the Quote model class has a method that returns the proposal property, perhaps `getProposal()` or `getProposals()`?

Comment: All the properties are protected, so not accessable from outside. As Mark said, there could be public getters in the class.

Comment: Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.

Comment: guys, have a function inside class `getProposals()` that returns `return $this->proposals;`. so how can i call with above data array.

Comment: @MarkBaker! you are right, now need to call that function. Help me how to call function with resultant array...?

Comment: `$arrayobject->getProposals();` will return the array of proposal objects; `$arrayobject->getProposals()[0];` will return the proposal object with index 0

Comment: Thankyou so much @MarkBaker!. Working fine.